# plot the results glm with multiple explanatories with 95% CIs

Tags: r, plot, glm, poisson

data:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(9.5638945103927, 13.7767187698566, 6.0019477258207, 
10.1897072092089, 15.4019854273531, 10.9746646056535, 12.9429073949468, 
20.7513493525379, 18.5764146937149, 2.91302077116471, 13.6523222711501, 
10.0920467755108), y = c(83.949498880077, 18.066881289085, 71.3052196358606, 
39.8975644317452, 57.2933166677927, 87.8484256883889, 92.6818329896141, 
49.8297961197214, 56.3650103496898, 14.7950650020996, 37.9271392096266, 
50.4357237591891), z = c("a", "c", "e", "f", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
"b", "a", "c", "d")), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

my model:

```
mod <- glm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + z, family=quasipoisson, data = df)
summary(mod)
```

I want to plot something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,
              formula=y~x+I(x^2),fill="transparent",
              colour="black") +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",geom="ribbon",
              formula=y~x+I(x^2),fill="transparent",
              colour="red",linetype="dashed",fullrange=TRUE) +
          scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-2,35)) +
          coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2,25),
                          ylim=range(pretty(df$y)))
```

[image]

However, the model I have plotted is obviously not the same model as `mod`, there is no `z` and it is not `quasiposson`.

How can I plot something like the ggplot but using my actual model? I have looked at `predict` however, I am completely lost what to do when there is more than one explanatory, as in my case. I don't care about doing it in `ggplot2`

Answer (score 7):

It would seems like you could trivially adapt your example to your new model by using `stat_smooth(method='glm', family=quasipoisson, ...)`, but adding the `z` into the formula leads to errors. Looking from the [ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_smooth.html), you can see that the `predictdf` is what is used to generate the limits for the intervals. Looking at the code for that function, it looks like it is only meant to work with predictions across the x dimension. But we can easily write our own version that works in multiple dimensions and then plot the limits as separate layers.

```
mypredictdf <- function (model, newdata, level=0.95){
  pred <- stats::predict(model, newdata = newdata, se =TRUE, type = "link")
  std <- qnorm(level/2 + 0.5)
  data.frame(newdata,
             y = model$family$linkinv(as.vector(pred$fit)),
             ymin = model$family$linkinv(as.vector(pred$fit - std * pred$se)),
             ymax = model$family$linkinv(as.vector(pred$fit + std * pred$se)), 
             se = as.vector(pred$se))
}
px <- with(df, seq(from=min(x), to=max(x), length=100))
pdf <- expand.grid(x=px, z=unique(df$z))
pdf <- mypredictdf(mod, newdata=pdf)
g <- ggplot(data=pdf, aes(group=z))
g <- g + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=z))
g <- g + geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax),
                     alpha=0.2)
g <- g + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, color=z))
```

[image: one panel]

It seems like faceting would be a good idea:

```
g <- g + facet_wrap(~z)
```

[image: facetted version]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach that deals with multiple variables ( `y = f(x,z)` in your case).

```
mod <- glm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + z, family=quasipoisson, data = df)
pred <- predict(mod, type="response",se.fit=T)
df$pred <- pred$fit
df$se   <- pred$se.fit

ggplot(df, aes(x=y))+
  geom_point(aes(y=pred, color=z),size=3)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=pred-se, ymax=pred+se, color=z),width=1.5)+
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, color="blue", linetype=2)+
  labs(x="Actual", y="Predicted")
```

[image]

This plots predicted y vs. actual y, grouped by z, with error bars = ±1 × se. To get 95% CL on the predicted, you would need to use ±1.96 × se. The dotted line is a reference (actual = predicted) which would represent a perfect fit. You can see from this that `z=b` and `z=c` are problematic, but `z in (a,d,e,f)` all fit the data rather well.

If you have more than 2 variables, the grouping becomes problematic, but the asic approach of plotting predicted y vs. actual y still applies.